# Tinymce Mobile shows blank screen

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to implement the "Mobile" theme from TinyMCE. When I use the editor on the desktop it works fine, but when I try it on my IPhone or with Chrome's device view it shows the "Open Book" icon and after a click, a white screen with no content is shown. There are also no console errors.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  menubar: false,
  statusbar: true,
  theme: 'modern',
  mobile: {
    theme: 'mobile',
    plugins: ['link'],
    toolbar: ['undo', 'redo', 'link'],
    language: 'en'
  }
})
```

When I execute this code in a fiddle it works, but it's not working on my website. Anyone any idea what is causing this?